# Ubuntu 13.10 installed and worked, but now not working

Tags: boot, 13.10

I have a HP G7000 laptop.

I updated/upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10, after the software updater recommended I upgrade.

I have duel booting system with Windows Vista.  The system was working for the past two days, but I start getting the errors below, after selecting Ubuntu in Grub Menu on startup and at the splash screen it says `"Press S to Skip or M for manual configuration"`

Pressing S gives a black screen and m takes you the errors below.

Windows boots and works fine after selection in the Grub Menu.

```
[   15.235703] EXT3-fs (sda5): error: unrecognized mount option "discard" or missing value.

[   16.788072] [drm:intel_pipe_config_compare] *ERROR* mismatch in adjusted_mode flags [expected 2, found 0]

[   20.860071] [drm:intel_pipe_config_compare] *ERROR* mismatch in adjusted_mode flags [expected 2, found 0]

[   20.980076] [drm:intel_pipe_config_compare] *ERROR* mismatch in adjusted_mode flags [expected 2, found 0]


Root filesystem Check failed

root@simamhar:~#
```

Tried boot-repair using the LiveCD method, no luck.  System still gives above error.
(you can view the boot-repair log here http://paste.ubuntu.com/6287287)

When I use the liveCD for 13.04 or 13.10 however, my hard disk is recognized and I can read the files.  Why is it that the installation on the hard disk has stopped working and does not recognize my / ?
What do the above errors mean and how can i solve them?

There was no power failure before, during or after the update/upgrade process from 13.04 to 13.10.

I now would like to go back to 13.04 without reinstalling afresh?

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an expert but it seems to be fstab problem. Check it out`sudo gedit /etc/fstab`
Did you move one of the partitions recently?

Comment: Hi Kenn, thanks for your reply.  I have not moved any partitions, simply updated/upgraded as suggested by software updater.  This issue started two days after upgrading.  I also cannot edit any files as once the system is at the prompt, it is "root" and no programs are running unless they are installed before.

Comment: May this thread be of help [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861277)

Answer (score 3):

The issue was the Intel Graphics Card and its drivers in the latest kernel.

I just upgraded to the latest kernel release.  Everything now works Great.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and it is to do with intel graphics cards, i have the i915. You need to download the latest drm fix which is not on updates yet.
Here is the link:
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~danvet/drm-intel/